# I have an issues with the date in python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I want to convert this type of date `%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S` into this type of date 
`%d-%m-%Y` in python using visual studio. can anyone help me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that you start with a string in the given format, i'd suggest:

```
import datetime as dt

dateStr = '2018-04-1912:30:35'
oldFormat = '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'
newFormat = '%d-%m-%Y'
formatedDate = dt.datetime.strptime(dateStr, oldFormat).strftime(newFormat)
```

formatedDate would be: `'19-04-2018'`

edit1:
Regarding the problem of formatting more than one date:

```
listOfDates = [d1, d2, ...]
f = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, oldFormat).strftime(newFormat)
newDates = map(f, listOfDates)
```

Here i defined a function f for the conversion and assume that you have a list(or other iterable), so that you can transform all the dates in one `map`-call.

edit2:
for '2016-10-16T00:00:00' the format string is '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', so the format you wrote about in your question with the extra T between date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `datetime` module, which is part of the standard library:

```
from datetime import datetime

x = '2018-05-1015:15:25'

res = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')\
              .strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

print(res)

# 10-05-2018
```

---

For a list of dates:

```
lst = ['2018-05-1015:15:25', '2017-12-0120:25:02']

res = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S').strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), lst))

print(res)

# ['10-05-2018', '01-12-2017']
```